# Add string only if is not present

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to add a string to a all fields on a column but only if that string is not present already?

This is the specific example of what I need to do. I have a table called contacts. I have a column on that table called website. Some websites have this format:

http://example.com

others have this format

example.com

The thing is that I need that all websites use this format http://example.com

I have to add http:// to the beginning of each field but only if http:// is not already there. I can't find a way to do it with this query:

```
UPDATE contacts SET website = CONCAT(website, 'http://');
```

It adds the http:// at the end and obviously even if the http:// is already there it add it again.

Is it possible what I need to do?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE contacts SET website = CONCAT('http://', website) WHERE (website != '') and (website NOT LIKE '%://%')
```

That should (a) put the `http://` at the beginning and (b) only add it if there is not already `http://` or `https://` or similar in the string.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Now I have a little problem. How can I also not add http:// when the field is empty? Not all the fields have a website in it so I want to leave them blank if they are already blank. Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE contacts SET website = CONCAT('http://', website) WHERE website NOT LIKE '%://%' AND website NOT LIKE ''